# Let $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded function. Which of the following $may$ be true statement(s)?

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Let $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded function. Which of the following $may$ be true statement(s)?

(a) $f$ attains infimum but not supremum.

(b) $f$ attains supremum but not infimum.

(c) $f$ attains neither a infimum nor a supremum.

(d) $f$ attains its supremum and infimum on any non-empty open interval $A \subset [0,1].$

> Solution:

Since the function $f$  is given to be bounded, it should have both- an upper bound and a lower bound, that means infimum and supremum must exist. Going by my claims, (a),(b),(c) would have been incorrect. But the answer key does not agree.

Also, i don't know how to verify option (d), why is it that  $f$ attains its supremum and infimum on any non-empty open interval $A \subset [0,1].$

The answer key says:

> (a),(b),(c),(d)

Comment: Key word is "attains".  For instance, $f(x)=x$ when $0<x<1$ and $f(0)=f(1)=0.5$ doesn't attain either $0$ or $1$

Comment: those statements need not to hold at the same time meaning you can find a bounded function that satisfy each one, for example, (d) is satisfied by the function f(x)=0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of $(a),(b),(c),(d)$ $\it{may}$ be true. For $(d)$ just consider the constant function $f(x)=1$.

For $(a)$ consider $f(x)=\sin(\pi x)\;\; (x\neq \frac{1}{2})$ with $f(\frac{1}{2})=0$. Here $f$ does not attain its supremum value $1$ but $f$ attains the infimum $0$ at $x=0,1,\frac{1}{2}$. For $(b)$ note that $-f$ attains its supremum of $0$ at $x=0,1,\frac{1}{2}$ but never attains its infimum of $-1$.

For $(c)$ define $f$ so that $f(x)=\sin(\pi x)\;\;(x\neq 0,\frac{1}{2},1)$ and $f(0)=f(\frac{1}{2})=f(1)=\frac{1}{2}$. Here, $f$ does not attain its supremum of $1$ or its infimum of $0$.